# Android asyncTask with get method not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am using http get to connect to a site and retrieve some data from it. For that purpose I needed to define `asyncTask` methods and using asyncTask get method to retrieve the result generated in `doInBackground` method.

My helper methods to get data from server are perfectly fine so no need to post them here. When I call `new LongOperation().execute().get()` then application crashes. When I debug the code it opens new window and displays `Source not Found`.

Here is my code:

`Main activity:`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_notification);
    try {
        ArrayList<Job> JobsStore = new LongOperation().execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    ...
```

`asyncTask Methods`:

```
public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Job>> {
private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
protected ArrayList<Job> doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList<Job> JobsStore = SendRSSFeed();
    return JobsStore;
}      

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Job> result) {    
    super.onPostExecute(result); 
}
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Post logcat please. Possibly `ArrayList<Job> JobsStore = SendRSSFeed();` line is throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: don't use `get()` because UI be freezing, instead of that use `onPostExecute` and work with data on that

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ArrayList<Job> JobsStore = new LongOperation().get();` ?

Comment: using get() defeats the purpose of asynctask. Its use is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LongOperation().execute().get()`, `execute()` starts running the async task and returns an instance of itself. Running `get()` on that returned instance runs the async task again, which does not seem to make sense.

So you can use `LongOperation().get();`.

See [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was with declaration of doInBackground method. The parameter must be set to `Void... params` instead of `String... params` because I was calling this method with zero parameters.

Comment: You shouldn't use `get()`, it is synchronous. It will freeze the UI `Thread` and it defeats the purpose of using an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Using `doInBackground(String... params)` with `AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<Job>>` would have shown error in the IDE itself because the parameter types do not match. I am surprised you were able to run the app in the first place with this issue.